# jQuery toggle only works on first div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying out jQuery and I've ran into a few problems.

```
<script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
          $("#hide").click(function(){
            $("#comm").slideToggle("fast");
            return false;
          });
        });
</script>
<div id="com">
 <button id="hide">Hide/show</button>
  <div id="comm">
    Data here         
  </div>
</div>
```

I have multiple #com div's that include the #comm div. But only the first button works. When I had a show/hide implementation, then the first button would control all of the comm divs on the page.

Currently, still, only the first button works and it only controls the first div instead of all.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `Ids` are supposed to be **unique**, you better use [Class Selector (“.class”)](http://api.jquery.com/class-selector/). Use [next()](http://api.jquery.com/next/) to get to the next sibling of current event source object using class `comm`

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/xeBnJ/)**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
      $(".hide").click(function(){
        $(this).next(".comm").slideToggle("fast");
        return false;
      });
});
```

> [next()](http://api.jquery.com/next/): Get the immediately following sibling of each element in the
>   set of matched elements. If a selector is provided, it retrieves the
>   next sibling only if it matches that selector, [jQuery Docs](http://api.jquery.com/next/).

If you have no option of changing the html then you can use [Attribute Equals Selector [name="value"]](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/) to bind the event but this is the last option and not recommended way.

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/xeBnJ/2/)**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
      $("[id=hide]").click(function(){
        $(this).next("#comm").slideToggle("fast");
        return false;
      });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using `id` for animation. Use `class` for that. When you use same `id` for multiple divs only first div is get selected, cause as per `html` guidelines `id` can be only use once throughout the page.

Comment: throughout the document context, a page can contain iframes ;) anyway +1

Answer (score 1):

```
<script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
          $("#hide").click(function(){
            $(".comm").slideToggle("fast");
            return false;
          });
        });
</script>
<div id="com">
 <button id="hide">Hide/show</button>
  <div class="comm">
    Data here         
  </div>
  <div class="comm">
    Data here         
  </div>
</div>
```

Use class with div. Id must be unique.